# Dealing with I18n within .js.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to make an IF statement depending on the language that triggers certain JS code.

temp.js.erb

```
<% if I18n.locale.to_s == 'es' %>
    someJScode;
<% elsif I18n.locale.to_s == 'en' %>
    someJScode;
<% elsif I18n.locale.to_s == 'eu' %>
    someJScode;
<% elsif I18n.locale.to_s == 'fr' %>
    someJScode;
<% end %>
```

Apparently it works. However, when I change the language on my app, the behavior of this code does not change. It still triggers the code of the previous locale.

Does not matter how many times I change the language. It will only trigger the code for the locale I opened the first window with.

Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

--------------------UPDATE------------

As suggested by @tigrish I iinstalled i18n-js gem.

I added this haml to my application.html.haml

```
:javascript
      I18n.defaultLocale = " I18n.default_locale ";
      I18n.locale = " I18n.locale ";
```

And tried to get the locale in JS the code provided in the gem docs.

```
var fo = I18n.currentLocale();
alert(fo);
```

However, it does not work.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I think @marcgg is probably right with regards to cacheing.

You might consider using https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js - even if you don't include any translations per se, your `I18n.locale == 'foo'` calls will all be in JS and interpreted every time the function runs.

Comment: Ok, I am gonna give it a try!

Comment: I did as you suggested. It looks pretty simple to implement. However, it does not do the trick for me. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: :javascript
      I18n.defaultLocale = "#{I18n.default_locale}";
      I18n.locale = "#{I18n.locale}";

Comment: Thanks for that. However I get this error in the console.
`TypeError: I18n.currentLocale is not a function`
I have tried to reinstall the gem but to not avail.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and @tigrish solution helped me to solve it.

@SergioNekora, please try those steps:

1. Install [i18n-js](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js) (by adding `gem 'i18n-js'` to your Gemfile).
2. Add to application.html.erb file (for haml file you should use some other syntax):

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       I18n.locale = "<%= I18n.locale %>";
   </script>`
   ```
3. Add to temp.js.erb/temp.js file `//= require i18n`
4. Now, you can use I18n.locale variable inside temp.js.erb/temp.js file (without using ruby). For example:

   ```
   if (I18n.locale) == 'es' {
        someJScode;
   } else if (I18n.locale == 'en') {
        someJScode;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that since it's javascript code it might be cached. Try clearing cache and checking if the language changes. If it does, either deactivate the cache for this file or make it depend on the locale.

Comment: You could be right. However, this might work for me. But other users might not clear the cache for it to work. Thus, I guess a better system. How would be that you have said 'make it depend on the locale'? Thanks

Comment: @SergioNekora When including the file, you could add the local a parameter to the file (just like rails does for with a sha to get the cache to expire when deploying a new version of the asset)

Comment: Could I? I don't really know how to do that.